# When should I use a prefix on Objective C classes?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, coding-style

According to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html), two to three letter prefixes should be used

> when naming classes, protocols, functions, constants, and typedef structures.

Does this include classes which are not intended to be part of a framework, simply used internally in an application?  I realize this is relying on other developers that develop frameworks you might be using to use prefixes, but that seems acceptable.  What about Core Data entities?  If I generate classes from them, shouldn't they be prefixed as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To be safe, use a prefix for all classes in your application.   All classes are loaded into a single flat namespace in Objective-C and the prefix prevents collisions both now and in the future.

This also includes CoreData entities; they should also use the same prefix as the rest of your application's classes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the CoreData entities.  I will say namespaces are one of the things I miss when writing Objective-C.

Comment: File a bug detailing why you need them.  It will be a dupe, of course, but your dupe & business case will be useful.

Comment: @bbum are you recommending the use of prefixes for entity names AND  names or just their objc class names? (I'd assume the latter given the entities' isolation within a given data model)

Comment: I'd keep the names consistent across the model and the classes.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that you may decide some of this code could be used elsewhere, so using prefixes now will safeguard you from potential collisions in the future.